# Is it possible to have a clear clean up of Windows XP without formatting the drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, formatting

I want to install a fresh Windows 7 but I don't want totally format the current drive with Windows XP since there are many other files but I don't have that many free space to move the stuff out. Is there a way to clean up the windows XP without formatting the drive?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do an upgrade installation from Windows XP to Windows 7, so formatting the drive and doing a clean install is actually necessary in your case, unfortunately.

What I would recommend is backing up any important files to a flash drive or portable hard drive, then install Windows 7 using a Custom Install option. You can follow the steps using [Microsoft's guide here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/help/upgrading-from-windows-xp-to-windows-7#T1=tab01).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the cloud services like SkyDrive (7GB Free) or Google Drive (15GB Free) or any of many others to save your files on.

Then format everything, make a clean install and download your files back to your PC

**Notice**:

**Save only your personal files and/or folders. Do not save programs and system data on cloud drives, as they will not work on a re-installed system.**